# run jar file by processBuilder

Tags: java, processbuilder

I have those code

```
URL location = ObjectUtil.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()
                .getLocation();
        String currentDir = location.getPath();
        String drive = currentDir.substring(1, currentDir.indexOf("WEB-INF") + 7);
        ArrayList<String> cmd = new ArrayList<String>();
        cmd.add("java");
        cmd.add("-cp");
        cmd.add(drive + "/lib/ksm2batch.jar");
        cmd.add("jp.co.kaneshindenki.ksm2batch.KSMBatchActionBase");
        cmd.add(jobId);
        cmd.add(serialized);
        cmd.add(serializedParam);
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd.toArray(new String[cmd.size()]));
        Process process = pb.start();
        InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader  br = new BufferedReader(r);
        String ch;
        while((ch = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(ch);
        }
```

these code run and call the the file Name KSMBatchActionBase and this file call "Bkh0020" file. And in "Bkh0020" file I have those code

```
System.out.println("1");
        _inParams.setJnlNo(Integer.parseInt(StringUtil.SafeString(parameter.get("JnlNo"), "0")));
        _inParams.setRerunKbn(StringUtil.SafeString(parameter.get("RerunKbn")));
        _inParams.setMotoId(StringUtil.SafeString(parameter.get("MotoId")));
        System.out.println("2");
```

the Process run and send back to me the output is "1", I don't have any else output of "2" or error message. I thought it die when I pass the value to _inParams Object. So anyone help me to resolve this problem. Many thanks for any answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If your program dies between printing `1` and printing `2`, the error message and the stack trace was probably written to `stderr`, and you're only reading `stdout`.

Redirect `stderr` to `stdout` by calling `pb.redirectErrorStream(true);` before the call to `pb.start()`.

---

Also the `ProcessBuilder` constructor that takes a `String[]` is actually a *vararg*, so your code can be changed to:

```
URL location = ObjectUtil.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
String currentDir = location.getPath();
String drive = currentDir.substring(1, currentDir.indexOf("WEB-INF") + 7);
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
    "java",
    "-cp",
    drive + "/lib/ksm2batch.jar",
    "jp.co.kaneshindenki.ksm2batch.KSMBatchActionBase",
    jobId,
    serialized,
    serializedParam
);
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = pb.start();
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))) {
    for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; ) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```